# Bubble sorting 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a 2d Array using bubble sort algorithm and i am constantly failing. What i need to do is to create a 2d array of random numbers 10-90 and find out the largest elements from each row after that sort that list of largest elements in ascending order using Bubble sort. I have done until finding the largest element from each row but i can not sort that list. The list of largest elements is saved in a variable called max. How can i sort that list using bubble sort. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Below is what I have tried so far:

//Write a program that fills the values of the two dimensional array A[N,M] with the random numbers from 10 to 90 and determines the largest value in each row. 
//Rows largest element values arrange in ascending order, using the "Bubble" sort algorithm. N and M input by the user.

```
int i,j,rows, columns, temp, swapped;
cout<<"How many rows? ";
cin>> rows;
cout<< "how many columns? ";
cin>>columns;

int array[rows][columns];

for(i = 0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        array[i][j] = rand()%90+10;
    }cout<<endl;
}

for(i = 0; i<rows; i++){
    for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
        cout<<array[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
for(i=0;i<rows;i++){

int max=array[i][0];

    for(j=0;j<columns;j++){

        if(max  <  array[i][j]){

        max = array[i][j];
    }

    }
        cout<<"Largest element in row" << i << "is: "<< max << endl;
}



    for(i=0; i<rows;rows++){

for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
    if(max > max+[1]){
        temp = max;
        max = max+[1];
        max+[1] = temp;

    }
}
    }



    for(i=0; i<rows;rows++){
for(j=0; j<columns; j++){
    cout<< max << endl; 
}
```

}

```
return 0 ;
```

}

Comment: Does this compile? What is ‘max+[1]’ supposed to do?

Comment: And the max around the same code block is undeclared, since ’int max’ goes out of scope with the upper for-loop

Comment: @GeckoGeorge, if you remove the code starting from while loop, It compiles until showing the largest elements of each row. what max+[1] is the second number in the list of largest elements. But, I think that is where i am going wrong, I need help at this sorting part. The list of largest elements in each row is saved in the variable max. I need to sort that list using bubble sort. I need help at this part.

Comment: Does the code that you've already written work? Do you know how bubble sort works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have trouble understanding how arrays and loops work. At first, read this article about [loops](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-c/), then this one about [multidimensional arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm). Now, as for your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows - 1; rows++) {
```

What are you actually doing here is incriminating `rows` variable, which stores number of rows in your `array[rows][columns]`. As a result, your loop doesn't work properly. To traverse through the array, you need to incriminate `i` variable, so you can access elements of the array by index withing square brackets.

For example: calling `array[i]`, while `i = 3`, will return you the fourth element of the array. (as arrays start at 0)

Now, sorting. You are trying to use `while (1)` loop, which is infinite, and break, which won't ever execute properly.

Sorting of two dimensional array is actually sorting ***x*** single dimensional arrays. So, what you need to do is to implement simple bubble sort for single dimensional array and wrap it up additional `for` loop to traverse trough rows.

```
int m;
int temp;
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // this will "switch" actual rows
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) { // this will traverse through elements
        for (m = 0; m < columns - 1; m++) {   // this will traverse just like the 
            if (array[i][j] > array[i][m]) {  // previous loop, but one element 
               temp = array[i][j];            // ahead, so you can compare them 
               array[i][j] = array[i][m];
               array[i][m] = temp;   // swapping elements array[row][element] 
                                     // with array[row][one element ahead]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### UPD:

To display array of max elements, at first create an array where you will keep your max values. For my snippet it is `int array_max[rows]`. It will record your max values as we find them. To do that, add this: (where you that cout was)

```
cout << "Largest element in row" << i << "is: " << max << endl;
        array_max[i] = max;
```

And now, to sort your new array and properly print it, try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < rows - 1; j++) {
        if (array_max[i] > array_max[j]) {
           temp = array_max[i];
           array_max[i] = array_max[j];
           array_max[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        cout << array_max[i] << " ";
}
```

And finally, add `#include <ctime>` to your project to get new random values each time you run your program.

Comment: If i execute code until: cout<<"Largest element in row" << i << "is: "<< max << endl; 
The output i am getting is:
56  40  10  63
18  80  83  73
57  35  36  82
68  59  86  18
Heighest value in row 0 is: 63
Heighest value in row 1 is: 83
Heighest value in row 2 is: 82
Heighest value in row 3 is: 86

I need to sort that heighest values list. I need help to sort this list of heighest values.

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank You so much @enjoy. That was so helpful. My problem is solved now and also i understand the whole thing.